# Setting scroll position on Kendo Angular Grid

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

When a grid is in a component at one route and the user navigates away and then comes back, the current kendo grid loses its scroll position and starts at the top.
Anyone know a way to "remember" the scroll position so it can be set on the grid manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a great solution, but it works for the time being. Here it is.
Inside the component with the grid:

```
private _scrollPos: number;

@ViewChild("grid", { read: ElementRef }) gridEl: ElementRef;

constructor(private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events.subscribe(e => {
        if (e instanceof NavigationStart) {
            let gridContent = this.getGridContentElement();
            if (gridContent.scrollTop > 0) {
                this._scrollPos = gridContent.scrollTop;
            }
        }
        else if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            if (this._scrollPos > 0) {
                let gridContent = this.getGridContentElement();
                gridContent.scrollTo({ top: this._scrollPos });
            }
        }
    }
}

private getGridContentElement(): Element {
    let el = this.gridEl.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    let gridContent = el.getElementsByClassName("k-grid-content").item(0);
    return gridContent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is can done by remembering which row was selected, saving the id of the row, and then setting the grid property **[selectedKeys]="id"** when the user navigates back.

For example if the data for the grid was based on product data then save last viewed row id (**ProductID**). When the user navigates back to grid, you can push the ProductID you saved to an array that is bound on the grid. This will make the row selected, to scroll to the row you can use the class **k-state-selected** and **scrollIntoView** to scroll the row into view.

This is a basic implementation, but should give you a enough to go on. I created a [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ba9e9) so you can see how to implement this. Make sure to configure the grid with **kendoGridSelectBy** and **selectedKeys**. The **kendoGridSelectBy** should match the id that you push to the array. In the example I created it was ProductID.

Comment: What about the virtualized scenario? User selects something at the bottom of a huge list, navigates away, comes back. The grid doesn't have the data anymore and can't select the previously selected row.
Or if the user makes no selection, I'd still want them to be able to go back and continue where they left off

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Grid `skip` to the same value it last was. You can check out the [persist state examples](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/how-to/persist-state/). The Grids use regular paging, but the same principles apply.

Comment: The skip is being stored and set, but the scroll position is lost. In the virtualized scenario, when a grid is shown, navigated away, and navigated back, the last data does actually load, but since the scroll position is back to 0, the rows shown are empty.

Comment: Sorry, my specific scenario involves custom route reuse strategy that stores and restores routes. In the case of a normal navigation and reuse strategy, the setting of a skip might actually work. Still, scroll position is lost whereas all other states are preserved.